# Como formatar DateTime em C#?

Tags: c#

conheço duas formas de formatar uma data em `C#`:

`data.ToShortDateString` que me dá um retorno assim: 21/07/2017

`data.ToLongDateString` que me dá um retorno assim: sexta-feira, 21 de julho de 2017

Quero um formato semelhante ao `ToLongDateString`, mas sem o dia da semana, ex:
21 de julho de 2017.

Como fazer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O [`ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) aceita formato.

Perceba que é necessário escapar a palavra "de" porque o `d` seria considerado como dia e que formatos de data são sensíveis à cultura da aplicação, então pode ser necessário especificar a cultura no método.

```
var dataFormatada = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd \"de\" MMMM \"de\" yyyy");
var data = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd \"de\" MMMM \"de\" yyyy", new CultureInfo("pt-BR"));
```

[Veja um exemplo no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/31VfM9)